# How do move controllers that's not in an area to an area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I started programming with MVC3 without any knowledge of areas. As the application grows bigger, I would like to use areas to organize my code, but most of my controllers are not inside any areas at all.

How do I quickly move an existing controller into an area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an Area, move your controller class file into the the `Controllers` folder of that area and then edit your controller namespace to match the `Area`. Then move your views into the area `Views` directory.

But be aware you have to update all links to that controller by having the area name in the URL.

Comment: Also move routes into the AreaRegistration  class. One of the good features of ASP MVC is the great flexibility that you have in how you lay out URLs, so surely you can keep the current set of URLs if you want? 

An area sets up routes for controllers within the area in the AreaRegistration class, and the default route is "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}". But it's just a default, if you want something else, just change it.